# Dealing with missing data for rating agencies, is deletion an accepted approach in this case?

Tags: r, statistics, missing-data, spss

I have a set of 72 public companies of the chilean stock exchange. The selection of the data wasn't random, as the choice of public companies was adressed first by those ones that have a total 24h market volume of at least 400 USD (yes, the stock exchange is small), for which I got the sample of 72 public companies.

The ESG ratings, are ratings that agencies give in order to measure the sustainability of a company. I used 4 different rating agencies.

The data is Missing at Random (MAR), as as the data is randomly missing for companies that aren’t part of the main chilean market index ("ipsa" you can ignore this). The data looks like this (on the table): (very few (like 5%) of the cases of companies that are in the main market index have missing values. Meanwhile for the other companies, missing values are in 70%+ of the cases.

| Companies | Agency 1 Rating | Agency 2 rating | is part of main index? |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 40 | 20 | yes |
| B | 20 | 30 | yes |
| C | 55 | 30 | yes |
| D | 55 | missing | yes |
| E | 70 | 30 | yes |
| F | 30 | 50 | yes |
| G | 30 | 60 | yes |
| H | 30 | 60 | yes |
| I | missing | 60 | no |
| N | 40 | missing | no |
| K | 20 | missing | no |
| L | 30 | missing | no |
| M | 40 | missing | no |
| Z | 20 | 20 | no |
| Y | 30 | 10 | no |

Is deletion of all those cases where the companies have missing values an accepted method to deal with these missing values to then run the correlation between ratings of different agencies, or am I doing a big mistake (big bias)?  I end up deleting almost all entries of the group of companies that aren't in the main market index, only two are remaining, while of the ones that are part of the market index, 26 remain. The total sample is 29 remaining alive, can I run correlation this way?

Comment: This brings us to a field of statistics called missing data imputation. One method is to remove rows with missing data entirely for any given analysis, but that may weaken the analysis. You can also impute the data with packages like MICE. If you still have questions after reading on how to handle missing data, then this is altogether a better question for CrossValidated as there is no concrete programming problem here.

Comment: Yes, please post this on [cross-validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)

Comment: I used another methodology to go forward. I considered only one group of data to do correlation analysis. Obviously mentioning this in the research.